# Ctrl + left/right arrow keys issue

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, gentoo

After the last system update the *ctrl + left/right arrow* command on *zsh* terminal doesn't do anything. Also ctrl+ u has something wrong because usually that command erase from the cursor to the beginning of the line, while now erase entire line..
Someone knows how to solve these problems?
thank you all.

Comment: Have you found any acceptable answer? I think Goncalo's answer is great.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

FWIW, this is what worked on my environment (rhel5.x) using zsh's default.

```
bindkey "^[[1;5C" forward-word
bindkey "^[[1;5D" backward-word
```

Comment: `^[^[[D` and `^[^[[C`, respectively, for OSX

Comment: Confirmed, Goncalo's proposal works also in Debian 8.5. I just wonder why this code is not built-in in `.zshrc` by default.

Comment: Works like a charm in Ubuntu Artful, thanks!

Comment: In case anyone wants to use `$terminfo` instead of the escape sequences: the keys `$terminfo[kLFT5]` and `$terminfo[kRIT5]` worked for me

Comment: This works, but why is it necessary? Why isn't this something taken care of via zsh defaults or via common options in the zsh "new user script"?

Comment: It's interesting that `"^[[1;5C"` and `"^[[1;5D"` work well directly on my mac 10.15.5

Comment: @Chiron It worked for me as well, BUT i had to disable "Mission Control" under Keyboard->Shortcuts in the System Preferences. 

Otherwise it'll intercept ctrl+left ctrl+right to switch between Desktops.

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all on zsh in iTerm2 on a recent MacBook Pro. Pressing the keys does nothing. I don't yet know why.

Comment: This also works in `csh` in the `.cshrc` file

Answer (score 23):

<kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd> is most likely because you've got the cursor at the end of the line.
Secondly, which version of Gentoo are you referring to as the "last system update"?

And what would you like the ctrl+left/right to do?

- Add to zsh config:

  ```
  bindkey '^[[1;5C' emacs-forward-word
  bindkey '^[^[[D' emacs-backward-word
  ```
- And from old scrap i found (might help):

  ```
  bindkey ";5C" forward-word
  bindkey ";5D" backward-word
  ```
- or have a look at [this](http://zshwiki.org/home/zle/bindkeys) link, which should help you out?

**Note**: If the config works but the supposed keys doesn't do what you want it's perhaps because the key-definition differs from yours and mine, do:

```
cat > /dev/null
```

and press the keys you'd like to get outputted and adjust accordingly.

Comment: "Ctrl+U is most likely because you've got the cursor at the end of the line" of course i mean when my cursor is in the middle."And what would you like the ctrl+left/right to do?" usually ctrl+left arrow : skip word going left etc...

Comment: And which shell/terminal are you using?
Makre sure you use Emacs or whatever terminal you usually use and /bin/bash? are you running through screen?

Comment: please read the question is there..

Comment: Sorry, missed that part.
Added a _possible__ solution, not sure if that helps you out tho but might.

Comment: Ctrl+U is bound to `kill-whole-line` by default. `bindkey "^U" backward-kill-line` should yield the desired behaviour.

Comment: @Masi Not sure, I answered two years before him and our answers are almost identical, I just showed two different ways to do it.. and you can merge them both to combine what he wrote.

Comment: @Masi All I know is that back then (remember, 2010-2012.. It was a long time ago) these two (and it's combination) worked for me on many different systems. I was on both Unix and Linux (and he was on Gentoo, a rolling release OS). And there's still traces of this on a lot of examples.. Such as [this](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/key-bindings.zsh) repository. Now, again, I'm not quite sure as to why but it worked on at least two machines so I thought I'd share it. And sure his is more clear TODAY, and I don't mind him getting all the up votes. This is a legacy post.

Comment: +1 for ";5C" and ";5D", working in RedHat 6 when other solutions didn't

Comment: bottom part works for ubuntu 19.10

Comment: +1 for the 
cat > /dev/null
trick to see your key sequence.

Answer (score 12):

What works **doesn't** directly depend on the distro (Gentoo, Debian, RHEL etc.) or the shell (ZSH, KSH, BASH) - it depends on which `terminal emulator` is used, and its settings: konsole, terminator, urxvt, lx-terminal etc.  The distro may matter if it uses a different standard shell config (fx. `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, `.inputrc`), and if using a different shell that shells config on that distro may already handle it.

Here are a few terminal emulator-specific solutions:

urxvt/rxvt-unicode  (and maybe others):

```
bindkey "^[Od" backward-word
bindkey "^[Oc" forward-word
```

alacritty, konsole, terminator, xterm (and maybe others):

```
bindkey "^[[1;5D" backward-word
bindkey "^[[1;5C" forward-word
```

For a more general approach you start your terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> followed by the key combination you want the escape code (the name) of - in this case the key combinations <kbd>Ctrl + Left Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + Right Arrow</kbd> - and put the output for each key combination in between the two quotes to make a keybind for it.

Comment: Did you try the CTRL-V suggestion? Maybe your terminal interprets the keystrokes differently, so the key needs to be bound to different "symbols"?

Comment: I updated my answer. There are multiple solutions depending on the `terminal emulator` used. The distro or shell doesn't matter. That's probably also why it's not in .zshrc, because what works for one terminal emulator doesn't work for another. But that could probably be solved if zshrc fx. read the $TERM environment variable and applied different bindkey settings based on the result.

Comment: This sounds correct, yet on my Mint (Ubuntu), bash is fine, while zsh is not. The user or system level .bashrc don't show `keybind` anywhere, so not sure why the difference.

Comment: Thanks, the later bindkey commands did the trick with Zsh in Alacritty.

Comment: mblakesley: Maybe it could be due to `.inputrc` then?

Comment: MetalGodwin: Glad to hear it - added it to the list.

Answer (score 6):

**Terminal used**: *Konsole*.

**To solve**: Right click on terminal (or *settings* in menubar) -> Change current profile > Keyboard mapping -> Change to Default (xfree4)

Comment: not even really related to zsh but sure, a fix is a fix.

Comment: Verified, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I came across this because I was having similar issues on a macbook using external keyboard.

Turns out ctrl+Left and ctrl+Right are set as **Keyboard shortcuts for mission control**.

Disabling this on the system fixed my issue

Adding

```
bindkey '\e\e[C' forward-word
bindkey '\e\e[D' backward-word
```

Enabled alt+right and alt+left to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Fixing this in *Konsole*: set `Right-Ctrl` and `Left-Ctrl` mappings same as they're in *Default(XFree_4)*: `\E[1;5D` and `\E[1;5C` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when I create `~/.inputrc` file with:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

context.so, I solved this issue by change it to below:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
```