# Why do control-left and control-right (arrow keys) not navigate by word in `less`?

Tags: terminal, less, input-method, user-input

In `less`'s line editing mode, the left and right arrow keys move the cursor backwards and forwards. I was hoping to use these together with the control key to navigate by word, as promised by `man less`.

```
       ^LEFTARROW [ ESC-b or ESC-LEFTARROW ]
              (That is, CONTROL and LEFTARROW simultaneously.)  Move the cursor one word to the left.

       ^RIGHTARROW [ ESC-w or ESC-RIGHTARROW ]
              (That is, CONTROL and RIGHTARROW simultaneously.)  Move the cursor one word to the right.
```

Unfortunately, this seems not to work in my terminal. (Tilix 1.8.3, VTE 0.52, GTK 3.22.30 on Fedora 28). Instead, pressing Control-left prints something I don't recognise. In the example below, I typed `alpha beta` and then immediately pressed Control-Left. This added `ESC[1;5D` to the line.

[image: [1]]

Is there some misconfiguration going on here? In other applications (e.g. `vim`) Control-Left and Control-Right navigate by word as intended.

FWIW, [Ctrl + left/right arrow keys issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58870/ctrl-left-right-arrow-keys-issue), might be related as might [Arrow keys in `less`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255920/arrow-keys-in-less)

Comment: Looks like `less` doesn't support (at least not out of the box) the standard escape sequences that Ctrl+arrow keypresses generate nowadays in `xterm` and many other terminal emulators. It probably supports an older one instead. It would be lovely if you reported this to `less`'s developer, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working in the end. (I contacted `less`'s author, whose response pointed out that I was making things a little more complicated than they needed to be.)

Here's the `lesskey` configuration file I ended up using.

```
#! /usr/bin/env lesskey
#line-edit
\e[1;5D word-left
\e[1;5C word-right
\e[3;5~ word-delete
```

Running lesskey on this file and starting a new instance made <kbd>Ctrl-←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-→</kbd> navigate by (space-delimited?) word, and <kbd>Ctrl-Delete</kbd> delete rightwards to the end of the current word. I guess the downside of this solution is that it's hard-coded to the particular escape sequences generated by my terminal emulator; the other answers explain why a generic "control+arrow key" mechanism wasn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Alt+w` and `Alt+b`

**w** will be used for forward search and **b** will be used for backward.

Answer (score 2):

## Because you are not using OS/2

I am not kidding.

[The OS/2 input handling code in `less`](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/d5015d29f79e70fb70489616c0f2d0ff32e52898/screen.c#L977) has a "special key" mapping for the <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> chords to its internal `SK_CTL_LEFT_ARROW` and `SK_CTL_RIGHT_ARROW` events.

The Unix code simply has no equivalent mapping.  It relies upon termcap, and termcap is notoriously deficient in this area.

What is in square brackets in the doco is right, and what is in parentheses is wrong.  You'll have to use <kbd>⎋ Escape</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>⎋ Escape</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>⎋ Escape</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> (sic!), and <kbd>⎋ Escape</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> (sic!) sequences (not chords, note) until someone makes `less` better.  Please file a report.

(In some terminal emulators, you can configure a modifier key to cause an <kbd>⎋ Escape</kbd> to be prefixed.  This is not true for all terminal emulators and terminals, in particular the ones whose input control sequences are being emulated here (which, rather, report modifiers in the CSI sequence), and the important part is that the first character received by `less` from the terminal is `␛`.  `less` itself has no notion of such a modifier.)

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444270/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465308/5132
- "[What if I find a bug in `less`?](http://greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html#bugs)".  *`less` FAQ*.  Greenwood Software.

Comment: Do we have any alternative that uses GNU `readline` so that I can play with `~/.inputrc`?

Answer (score 1):

**`less`** is a [*termcap*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#uses_of_library) application, using the termcap interface to obtain all of the information it "knows" about a given terminal.  *Unless* its developer introduces some ***hard-coded*** behavior (as done in a very few programs which I won't mention), **`less`** will provide no support for those key combinations because they are not standard features (see for instance the  *termcap* column of the capabilities listed in ncurses' [terminfo(5)](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Predefined-Capabilities)), and have no **2**-character names assigned to them (see the [terminal database](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_N_C_U_R_S_E_S__U_S_E_R-_D_E_F_I_N_A_B_L_E__C_A_P_A_B_I_L_I_T_I_E_S) for a summary of extensions).

By the way, referring to [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255920/arrow-keys-in-less) and taking a quick look at less's [source-code](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/7f627764370b46a09b22bd59156e0819811179ee/decode.c#L42), I do not see anything that corresponds to left/right ***word*** movement (unless that is the intended meaning of the left/right shift **`A_LSHIFT`** and **`A_RSHIFT`**).  *git blame* says those as well as the manual page comment about "word" date back to 2007 (version 394).  These look more promising (from 2016):

```
    SK(SK_CTL_RIGHT_ARROW),0,       A_RRSHIFT,
    SK(SK_CTL_LEFT_ARROW),0,        A_LLSHIFT
```

but the checkin comment only says

```
commit e5c195113d1666ac506ea3f65545d436d96fe099
Author: Mark Nudelman <markn@greenwoodsoftware.com>
Date:   Sat Oct 22 15:25:44 2016 +0000

    New commands ESC-{ and ESC-} to shift to start/end of displayed lines.
```

Reading the code (in [command.c](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/master/command.c#L1900)) for shifting, I did not see anything that disagrees with the conclusion that **`less`** scrolls by *columns* (single characters) rather than *words*, but OP's comment pointed to these:

```
    ESC,SK(SK_LEFT_ARROW),0,        EC_W_LEFT,      /* ESC LEFTARROW */
    SK(SK_CTL_LEFT_ARROW),0,        EC_W_LEFT,      /* CTRL-LEFTARROW */
    ESC,'w',0,                      EC_W_RIGHT,     /* ESC w */
    ESC,SK(SK_RIGHT_ARROW),0,       EC_W_RIGHT,     /* ESC RIGHTARROW */
    SK(SK_CTL_RIGHT_ARROW),0,       EC_W_RIGHT,     /* CTRL-RIGHTARROW */
```

which use [<kbd>space</kbd>](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/master/cmdbuf.c#L868) as a delimiter for "words". Perhaps when the developer made those changes, he had in mind imitating vi, which can do both (though vi's *words* are delimited differently).

The suggested <kbd>*Escape</kbd><kbd>*left-arrow*</kbd>, etc., are provided using these lines from the table:

```
    ESC,SK(SK_LEFT_ARROW),0,        EC_W_LEFT,      /* ESC LEFTARROW */

    ESC,SK(SK_RIGHT_ARROW),0,       EC_W_RIGHT,     /* ESC RIGHTARROW */
```

However—the current program does not contain any *assignments* using those `SK_CTL_RIGHT_ARROW` or `SK_CTL_LEFT_ARROW` symbols.  That would be done in *lesskey*, e.g., in this [case statement](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/master/lesskey.c#L406) (or close by, at any rate):

```
            switch (*++p)
            {
            case 'u': ch = SK_UP_ARROW; break;
            case 'd': ch = SK_DOWN_ARROW; break;
            case 'r': ch = SK_RIGHT_ARROW; break;
            case 'l': ch = SK_LEFT_ARROW; break;
            case 'U': ch = SK_PAGE_UP; break;
            case 'D': ch = SK_PAGE_DOWN; break;
            case 'h': ch = SK_HOME; break;
            case 'e': ch = SK_END; break;
            case 'x': ch = SK_DELETE; break;
            default:
                error("illegal char after \\k", NULL_PARG);
                *pp = p+1;
                return ("");
            }
```

Without assignments in the code, those are hard-coded only, not configurable.

The MSDOS / OS/2 configurations differ from the Unix one by having a (hard-coded) table of [key codes](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/master/screen.c#L885):

```
#if MSDOS_COMPILER || OS2
        static char k_right[]           = { '\340', PCK_RIGHT, 0 };
        static char k_left[]            = { '\340', PCK_LEFT, 0  };
        static char k_ctl_right[]       = { '\340', PCK_CTL_RIGHT, 0  };
        static char k_ctl_left[]        = { '\340', PCK_CTL_LEFT, 0  };
```

and provides for using those in a [case statement](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/master/screen.c#L948):

```
#if MSDOS_COMPILER || OS2
        case SK_INSERT:
                s = k_insert;
                break;
        case SK_CTL_LEFT_ARROW:
                s = k_ctl_left;
                break;
        case SK_CTL_RIGHT_ARROW:
                s = k_ctl_right;
                break;
```

(note: still no assignments, hence the cases are unused), while in the termcap configuration, those symbols are not used at all.  (termcap is "extensible", and if you took the trouble to invent 2-character mnemonics for your own use and modify less to implement those cases, it would do what you want).

Revisiting lesskey's [manual page](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/7f627764370b46a09b22bd59156e0819811179ee/lesskey.nro.VER#L112), it says this:

> An action may be followed by an *"extra"* string.  When such a command is
>   entered while running less, the action is performed, and then the extra
>   string is parsed, just as if it were typed in to  less.   This  feature
>   can  be used in certain cases to extend the functionality of a command.
>   For example, see the **"{"** and **":t"** commands in the example  below.   The
>   ***extra***  string  has  a  special meaning for the *"quit"* action: when less
>   quits, first character of the extra string is used as its exit status.

That implies that you could do something like this:

```
\e[1;5D     noaction \e\e[D
\e[1;5C     noaction \e\e[C
```

to map into an *extra string* which uses the predefined word-shift.

Comment: `Esc ←` and `Esc →` navigate by what looks like words to me (as in [JdeBP's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506578/190092)). Note that there are separate binds and commands for the "text buffer" you get at the bottom of less, and in particular [EC_W_LEFT](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/7f627764370b46a09b22bd59156e0819811179ee/decode.c#L189) which seems promising.

Perhaps I can use [lesskey(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lesskey) to make less treat whatever input it is getting as if it was getting `Ctrl-←` and `Ctrl-→`; I will investigate.

Comment: I see - will update

Comment: Thank you for your thoroughness. Do I understand you and the source code correctly?

1. There is no way for lesskey to generate a `SK_SPECIAL_KEY` string whose second (i.e. index 1) character is SK_CTL_LEFT_ARROW. This is because there is no standard termcap 2-character mnemonic for the `Ctrl-←` chord.

2. This means there is no way to "hit" the
`SK(SK_CTL_LEFT_ARROW),0, EC_W_LEFT, /* CTRL-LEFTARROW */`
[entry in the `edittable`](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/7f627764370b46a09b22bd59156e0819811179ee/decode.c#L189) which in order to trigger the `EC_W_LEFT` "action".

Comment: right less doesn't ask tgetstr for a capability, and none is defined (terminfo uses more than 2 characters) and lesskey doesn't have a way to set the value.  As I read it, you can only get to those word-shifts using the escape+key stuff.

Comment: The `noaction` approach looks promising. `lesskey` doesn't like using the `noaction` action within a `#line-edit` section, I assume because [there is no entry in `editnames`](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/master/lesskey.c#L154-L177). There is a code `EC_NOACTION` which is [used here](https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/7f627764370b46a09b22bd59156e0819811179ee/cmdbuf.c#L930) but not assigned anywhere.